PHP Variable in Table Name of SQL Statement
I am getting a syntax error in my PHP code when attempting to select a table that contains a variable. I have tried several different solutions on other threads and all throw the same error.
Here is my current code:
$ladderid = 'ladder_id_' . $ladder['id'];
$ranker=mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT teamid,rank,wins,loss,streak 
       FROM '" . $ladderid . "' WHERE sid = '".$ladder['season']."' AND active='1' ORDER BY points DESC, rank ASC");
       while(list($teamid,$rank,$wins,$loss,$streak)=mysqli_fetch_row($ranker)){

The error is coming from the table name. If I use this it works fine
$ranker=mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT teamid,rank,wins,loss,streak 
      FROM ladder_id_1 WHERE sid = '".$ladder['season']."' AND active='1' ORDER BY points DESC, rank ASC");
      while(list($teamid,$rank,$wins,$loss,$streak)=mysqli_fetch_row($ranker)){

Per other solutions on Stack Overflow, I have tried to wrap $ladderid in {} to no success. Here is the error in my error log

AH01071: Got error 'PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught
mysqli_sql_exception: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right
syntax to use near ''ladder_id_1' WHERE sid = '1' AND active='1' ORDER
BY points DESC, rank ASC' at line 2 in

So it is obviously passing the variable into the sql syntax but it's for some reason not liking it. Any idea what I could be missing here?

You appear to be looking at a V.V Old tutorial. If a tutorial uses values concatenated into the query string it should be ignored as dangerous. Take a look at this Q&A to find out about SQL Injection Attack
